# Links to answers

Tags: support

Sometimes (on meta as well as on main) I want to link to an answer. It is possible to get a link to a comment: by clicking on the timestamp you get a link with on the end something like `#comment109723_57751`. Do we have something similar with answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, click the share button below the answer/question for a link.

[image: Image of the button push]

It includes your userid in the link so that it can track and give badges for how many you refer to the question/answer. It is the last number, you can remove it manually if you like.

Comment: Eh, oops. Thanks, I'll change the question to `support` as well.